# Python - Interactive Web Portal

Tags: python, bottle

I have built a fully functioning Python script that completes a variety of Network automation tasks.

It currently sits and operates on a Windows Server without any issues.

I now wish to access this script via a web portal so that I can easily share the tool.

I've tried a few solutions including Bottle, but to be honest I'm not having any luck. I have Bottle running but I just can not work out a way to call and run my script.

I just need a web page that I can access on my local LAN which when accessed opens up an interactive shell which runs my script... Easy :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) as a simple web server:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def handler():
  do_something()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

This application will run in port 5000, so whenever you navigate to http://your-computer-name:5000/ the function do_something() will be called.

This is not suitable for high loads, but to get you started, it's probably the easiest.

Comment: Thanks for this I'll give it ago today and report back. Is it possible for "Do Something" to call another Python script so that I do not have to manipulate the working code I have in another script?

Comment: You can import those scripts and use them